# Issue with header casing Content-Type vs content-type

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

Just started seeing an issue wherein Chrome using the Headers class adding headers are lower-cased. I.e. when I add `Content-Type` it is changed to `content-type`. This seems to be blocking calling Graph as I get back a response as below. I confirmed that the header was present, however, it had been transformed to lowercase. Can the service be updated to accept case-insensitive headers?

```
{
    "status": 415,
    "statusText": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "data": {
        "responseBody": {
            "error": {
                "code": "",
                "message": "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
                "innerError": {
                    "request-id": "7032e0e0-32f5-47b5-a328-de8c12576cd4",
                    "date": "2018-03-16T13:28:30"
                }
            }
        },
        "responseHeaders": {}
    },
    "name": "ProcessHttpClientResponseException"
}
```

This is the headers from a request:

```
POST /v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks? HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
authorization: Bearer {token}
Origin: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json;
Accept: */*
Referer: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/sitepages/webpacktest.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
DNT: 1
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddler trace showing the call itself (and it's headers)?

Comment: Added above, can't format here in comments

Comment: So actually, now I am not sure. I have added in a patch immediately before the fetch request is sent forcing the header casing but I get back the same response from this call, even with "correctly" cased header. So might not be casing issue after all, will try test with a few other calls.

Comment: Thank you for updating. I was not able to reproduce this and couldn't for the life of me figure out why we would get different results. Could you add the call your making and the payload to the question?

Comment: Marc - this is 100% my bad. Thanks for having a look, was an extra character ";" in the header value.

Answer (score 0):

This is user error. Was sending value of content-type as "application/json;". Removing the ";" and sending "application/json" resolves this. Casing is not an issue.